# 定義済みの関数をリネームする方法はありますか？

Tags: bash

```
command_not_found_handle () {
    if [[ "$1" =~ [[:digit:]][d+-] ]]; then
        dice "$1"
        return $?
    elif [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
        /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1";
        return $?;
    else
        if [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
            /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1";
            return $?;
        else
            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2;
            return 127;
        fi;
    fi
}
```

上記のように.bashrcで`command_not_found_handle()`を再定義して、特徴的な引数なら該当するプログラムに渡すようにしました。
オリジナルの関数をそのままコピーしてきて冒頭に処理を挟み込んだのですが、予めオリジナルの関数を`command_not_found_handle_orig()`みたいにリネームしておいて最後に呼び出せばよりスマートだと思いました。

```
command_not_found_handle () {
    if [[ "$1" =~ [[:digit:]][d+-] ]]; then
        dice "$1"
        return $?
    else
        command_not_found_handle_orig "$1"
    fi
}
```

自前で再定義せずに関数の名前だけ変える方法か`type command_not_found_handle | tail --lines=+3`の出力を利用して関数を再定義する方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: [How do I rename a bash function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203583/how-do-i-rename-a-bash-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash でよいなら、`declare -f` を使ったハックが出来ます。

```sh
#!/bin/bash

foo () {
    echo foo
}

eval "orig_$(declare -f foo)"

foo () {
    orig_foo "$@";
    echo bar
}

# ここで foo を呼び出すと foo bar が出力されます。
foo
```

ただしシェルスクリプトは[動的スコープ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8B%95%E7%9A%84%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97)を採用しているので、上の方法は一般的な状況においては使えないことに注意してください。気になる場合、単に元の定義を新しい定義に手でコピペする方が良いです。

まず、`.bashrc` のようにトップレベルで評価される場合、他の箇所で `orig_foo` が定義されていないことを確認してください。既存の `orig_foo` を上書きしてしまったり、他の `orig_foo` で上書きされてしまうかもしれません。

また、関数が再帰呼び出しを含む場合、 **上のコードだと上手くいきません。** これをするためには関数定義のどの部分が関数呼び出しになっているのか分析できないといけないように思います。また、シェルスクリプトにおいては文字列操作の結果関数呼び出しが生まれる可能性があるので、そこまで対応しようと思うと更に困難になりそうです。

参考: [How do I rename a bash function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1203583/5989200) -- 本家 Stack Overflow

Comment: @伽語蓮弥 さん、一般的な状況においてこの方法は危険であることに気付いたので編集しました。内容をご確認ください。

Comment: `set`の出力を確認してみたところ、手元では少なくとも今回の目的に関しては問題なく動作してくれているようです。ちなみに`eval "orig_$(type command_not_found_handle | tail --lines=+2)"`でも同様の問題が起こりうるという理解でいいのでしょうか？

Comment: `eval "orig_$(declare -f command_not_found_handle | sed --expression='2~1s/command_not_found_handle/orig_&/g')"`みたいな感じで置換すれば再帰呼び出しに関しては解決できそう？

Comment: @伽語蓮弥 さん、はい、`tail` を使っても同様の問題が起こります。また、少なくともその `sed` の使い方だと再帰呼び出しに関する問題は解決しません。後者に関してもう少し詳しく言うと、たとえば関数 `foo` の定義の中に `foo` の呼び出しがある場合、変換の際にそこを全部 `orig_foo` に直さないといけないわけですが、単に `sed` で `foo` を `orig_foo` に置換するだけだと `echo foo` などの関係ない部分も置換されてしまうので困ります。また、極端に言うと `"f""o""o"` と書いても関数 `foo` を呼び出せるので、やはり困ります。

Comment: ああ、言われてみれば……。この手法は副作用に十分に注意しながら使わせてもらいます。